# How Do I Make My Website Show Input Cannot Be Blank With JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a javascript that redirects users to a URL if their input matches the result in my javascript but I noticed that the user will still be redirected to the URL even when they leave the input field blank.
How do I make an alert that says "Input cannot be blank" when they leave the input field blank?

Below is my javascript code.

```js
/* myScript.js */
function check(form)/*function to check userid & password*/
{
 /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
 if(form.userid1.value == "5089")
  {
alert("An account already exists with this  number! Kindly login to continue.")/*displays error message*/
    
  }
 else
 {
   window.location.replace('https://www.google.com')/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Adding the required attribute on the input element will solve.

Comment: DONT VALIDATE PASSWORDS ON THE CLIENT SIDE.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just add condition for blank value

```js
/* myScript.js */
function check(form)/*function to check userid & password*/
{
 /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
 if(form.userid1.value == "5089")
  {
alert("An account already exists with this  number! Kindly login to continue.")/*displays error message*/
    
  }
 else if(form.userid1.value == "" || form.userid1.value == null)
 {
   alert("Input cannot be blank");
 }
 else
 {
   window.location.replace('https://www.google.com')/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
  }
}
```

Comment: you can also use required attribute in input tag that will also solve issue

Answer (score 0):

```
  <input type="text" required value="" />
```

*Adding a required attribute will not allow the blank fields associated from to submit.*

Answer (score 0):

Our browsers are super smart nowadays, it's all in the box with just pure html.

[image]

Wrap your input in a `<form>`, and pass the `required` parameter in the desired `<input>`.

If the value is empty when submitting, the message `Please fill out this field` appears, and the input get a red border.

```html
<form>
  <input required placeholder="Field required*">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```